# Is there any chance ajax call to finish after the next line of code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
        var info = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "controller",
            type: "post",
            data : info,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                 $('.valid').html(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault()
    });
    $(".mainbutton").click(function(){
        $("#ajaxform").submit();
        if($('.valid').html(data) == "success"){ // could this fail?
            var info = $("#ajaxform").serialize();
            $.get("controller", info);
        }
    });
```

I am making ajax call and in the response I put "success". Is there any chance if($('.valid').html(data) == "success") to be called before and of ajax call and in fact fail the if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. Ajax calls are *asynchronous*. Therefore, you cannot expect a sequential flow. It is better to handle in the callback like

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
    var info = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "controller",
        type: "post",
        data : info,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
             $('.valid').html(data);
             if($('.valid').html(data) == "success"){ 
                 var info = $("#ajaxform").serialize();
                 $.get("controller", info);
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault()
});
$(".mainbutton").click(function(){
    $("#ajaxform").submit();
});
```

Comment: @oronaparcali, this may be for other reasons. Make sure you are entering the if statement by putting a console.log in there

Comment: @oronaparcali, can you replicate it in a fiddle so I can better help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.promise().done();**

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                 $('.valid').html(data).promise().done(function(){
                      $.get("controller", info);
                 });
            }

$(".mainbutton").click(function(){
    $("#ajaxform").submit();
    // or
    //$("#ajaxform").trigger('submit');
});
```

for more information about .promise().done() take a look at http://digitizor.com/2013/08/03/jquery-html-callback-function-using-promise/